# php resumable download. Browser do not want to show a progress

Tags: php, google-chrome, browser, download

First of all: I was trying to find a solution using stack overflow "similar questions" and google. Maybe I just didn't see it, but..

I wrote a PHP class which force file downloading. And give a header 'accept ranges: bytes'.

What am I doing wrong? Browser (Google Chrome) shows me zero progress and speed of downloading 0 kb/sec ( i decrease speed by sleep() func. ). But after Browser finish its download - in a moment shows me 100% progress. Why browser doesn't want to show its progress smoothly?

file downloader software works perfectly with this: shows correct progress, and can work with pause\resume download.
Log of this software:

```
[17:27:50.347] Thread main : task started
[17:27:50.348] Thread main : thread 1 started
[17:27:50.348] Thread main : thread started
[17:27:50.349] Thread main : connecting
[17:27:50.350] Thread main : localhost:80
[17:27:50.351] Thread main : localhost:80
[17:27:50.351] Thread main : GET /fs-debug.png HTTP/1.1
               Thread main : User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.77.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Safari/537.77.4    
               Thread main : Host: bonell
               Thread main : Pragma: no-cache
               Thread main : Accept: */*
               Thread main : Connection: close
               Thread main : Cache-Control: no-cache
               Thread main : Referer: http://bonell/
[17:27:51.464] Thread main : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
               Thread main : Date: Mon, 14 Sep 2015 14:27:50 GMT
               Thread main : Server: Apache
               Thread main : X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.28
               Thread main : Last-Modified: Mon, 14 Sep 2015 12:41:16 GMT
               Thread main : Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
               Thread main : Expires: Mon, 14 Sep 2015 14:27:50 GMT
               Thread main : Cache-Control: post-check=0,pre-check=0
               Thread main : Cache-Control: max-age=0
               Thread main : Pragma: no-cache
               Thread main : Connection: close
               Thread main : Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary
               Thread main : Content-disposition: attachment; filename="tst.png"
               Thread main : Accept-Ranges: bytes
               Thread main : Content-Length: 27314
               Thread main : Content-Type: image/png
[17:27:51.465] Thread main : saved to /Users/LINKeR/Downloads/fs-debug.1.png.folx/fs-debug.1.png
[17:27:51.466] Thread main : saved to /Users/LINKeR/Downloads/fs-debug.1.png.folx/fs-debug.1.png
[17:27:54.392] Thread main : socket closed
[17:27:54.393] Thread main : thread completed
[17:27:54.393] Thread main : thread 1 completed
[17:27:54.394] Thread main : task stopped
```

And after this I click "resume download" and it's works:

```
[17:34:17.379] Thread main : GET /fs-debug.png HTTP/1.1
               Thread main : User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.77.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Safari/537.77.4
               Thread main : Host: bonell
               Thread main : Pragma: no-cache
               Thread main : Accept: */*
               Thread main : Connection: close
               Thread main : Cache-Control: no-cache
               Thread main : Referer: http://bonell/
[17:34:19.420] Thread main : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
               Thread main : Date: Mon, 14 Sep 2015 14:34:17 GMT
               Thread main : Server: Apache
               Thread main : X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.28
               Thread main : Last-Modified: Mon, 14 Sep 2015 12:41:16 GMT
               Thread main : Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
               Thread main : Expires: Mon, 14 Sep 2015 14:34:18 GMT
               Thread main : Cache-Control: post-check=0,pre-check=0
               Thread main : Cache-Control: max-age=0
               Thread main : Pragma: no-cache
               Thread main : Connection: close
               Thread main : Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary
               Thread main : Content-disposition: attachment; filename="tst.png"
               Thread main : Accept-Ranges: bytes
               Thread main : Content-Length: 27314
               Thread main : Content-Type: image/png
[17:34:19.421] Thread main : socket closed
[17:34:19.421] Thread main : Checking Size
[17:34:19.422] Thread main : connecting
[17:34:19.423] Thread main : localhost:80
[17:34:19.423] Thread main : localhost:80
[17:34:19.424] Thread main : GET /fs-debug.png HTTP/1.1
               Thread main : User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.77.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Safari/537.77.4
               Thread main : Host: bonell
               Thread main : Pragma: no-cache
               Thread main : Accept: */*
               Thread main : Connection: close
               Thread main : Cache-Control: no-cache
               Thread main : Range: bytes=4096-
               Thread main : Referer: http://bonell/
[17:34:19.462] Thread main : HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
               Thread main : Date: Mon, 14 Sep 2015 14:34:19 GMT
               Thread main : Server: Apache
               Thread main : X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.28
               Thread main : Last-Modified: Mon, 14 Sep 2015 12:41:16 GMT
               Thread main : Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
               Thread main : Expires: Mon, 14 Sep 2015 14:34:19 GMT
               Thread main : Cache-Control: post-check=0,pre-check=0
               Thread main : Cache-Control: max-age=0
               Thread main : Pragma: no-cache
               Thread main : Connection: close
               Thread main : Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary
               Thread main : Content-disposition: attachment; filename="tst.png"
               Thread main : Accept-Ranges: bytes
               Thread main : Content-Range: bytes 4096-27313/27314
               Thread main : Transfer-Encoding: chunked
               Thread main : Content-Type: image/png
[17:34:19.463] Thread main : saved to /Users/LINKeR/Downloads/fs-debug.1.png.folx/fs-debug.1.png
```

Comment: usually if the browser doesn't show the progress is because the header `Content-Length` is missing, show us your PHP code

Comment: Yep. Usualy.. But I set it:
Content-Range: bytes 4096-27313/27314
Content-Length: 27314

Look at it please.

Comment: try with a bigger file (some MB), maybe chrome disallow progress/resume for a 27KB file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is already answered in the comments but I'll report it here for future reference.

It looks like that Chrome, even with all the correct headers in place (`Content-Length` and `Accept-Ranges: bytes`), disables progress reporting and download resuming for small sized files.

Try with a bigger file and it should work.

Comment: btw. I checked how does chrome downloader works: I use 2 functions in my script: "_showAll();" and "_showPartial($byteStart, $byteEnd);".

So with this actions "start->pause->resume->pause->resume->finish" File download client use "_showPartial" function, but chrome seems like keep connection alive, and don't download content on pause. I discovered it by writing log in these functions.